# I can passed data from one Activity to another Activity but Application crash

Tags: android

From First Activity Code

```
String value="7u1JgjTqaYo";
Intent loginintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class).putExtra("VIDEO_KEY",value);
startActivity(loginintent);
```

Second Activity Code here

```
public class Main2Activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String VIDEO_ID = intent.getStringExtra("VIDEO_KEY");

    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    Button btnPlay;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;
}
```

Comment: Please show the logcat error.

Comment: If you're initializing intent in declaration section, then that's wrong. Get intent in onCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my MainActivity intent:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String value="7u1JgjTqaYo";

        Intent loginintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)
                .putExtra("VIDEO_KEY",value);

        startActivity(loginintent);
    }
```

And this is my SecondActivity where I get the bundle:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        String apiKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_KEY");
        Toast.makeText(this, apiKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This code is working properly. Are you getting the Bundle in the onCreate method?

I hope it helps you